# Angular how to display a string from typescript to HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to coding so I have
`<strong> ValueFromTypeScript </strong>`
in my html
and I want to pull `name` from my ts file
`name:string = "George";`
is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, what have you tried. Please share a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply tried this

```
<strong> {{name}}</strong>
```

here `{{}}` is called string interpolation.

Have a look in angular documentation

https://angular.io/tutorial

This has sample app as well which we surely give you good understanding

Comment: The property is called `name`.

Comment: oh.. thanks @ConnorsFan.. I did typo error corrected now

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation to achieve that...refer [this](https://www.tutorialandexample.com/string-interpolation-in-angular-8/) to know more

In your case it would be

```
 <strong> {{ name }} </strong>
```